# I am new to Node js; and am having trouble using starting using it

Tags: node.js, windows

I have already installed node.js from the website, but when I type in install npm after the directions in the command line; it states "unexpected token: Illegal". How do I fix this? Is there a very specific step by step way to install node.js and package.json?

Comment: Please add your package.json and app.js (or server.js, index.js, whatever you run `node [js file]` with to your question.

Comment: The first thing you have to do here on stack overflow is learn how to ask much clearer questions.  We don't know where you've installed node.js, how you've installed node.js, what directory you're in, what exactly you're typing from that directory and what directions you claim to be following.  We can't help you here without a very clear and on-topic question.

Comment: I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PfSwUOBL1YQ which has lead me to download node.js from the website; honestly I am confused about how I download what I need to make a online game like in the video .

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do:

If you want to create a new application from scratch:

```
md myapp
npm init
```

Then answer the questions `npm` asks you.
`npm init` creates a `package.json` for you.

Now you can install other packages like `express` using `npm installl --save express`

If you have been cloning a Node.js app or module from GitHub, change into the directory, then run:

```
npm install
```